# Gridview CSS borders inconsistent

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview, cross-browser, border

This is really bugging me. I'm using a GridView and want to format it in such a way that the borders are displayed the same in all browsers. At the moment, I'm getting varying results between IE, FF and Chrome. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in my CSS (I'm quite new to CSS) but something must be right as one of the browsers displays the borders correctly at any time.
The gridview CSS is as follows:

```
.gridViewData
{
    height:auto;
    width:544px;
    position:relative;

    text-align:center;

     background-color:#7D9EBA;
     border:solid thin black;
     border-right:none 0px black;



}

.gridViewData td 
{
    padding:2px;
    border-top-style:none;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-right-style:none;
    border-color:Black;
    border-width:thin;



}

.gridViewData th
{
    height:10px;
    width: 544px;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    border-top-style:dashed;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-right-style:none;
    border-color:Black;
    border-width:thin;
    background-color:white;


}

.gridViewData .alt
{
     background-color:Red; 
}

.gridViewData .pgr 
{ 
    background-color:Orange; 
}
```

I'd like the table to look like this crude attempt at a drawing :D. The header should have no borders between the cells.

```
 ____________________________
|____________________________|
|___|__________|________|____|
|___|__________|________|____|
|___|__________|________|____|
```

In IE, the header has no top border. In FF, it looks fine an in Chrome there are separators in the header.
This has been bugging me for a while, so hopefully someone can shed some light on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the GridView properties to achieve this rather than applying CSS to the generated table elements. For example, the header can be styled by applying the CSS to the  property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.headerstyle.aspx

**EDIT:**

Note that the declarative bordercolor attribute adds an inline style declaration which only applies to the table itself, not individual cells. Adding the bordercolor attribute programmatically does not use an inline style, but uses the HTML bordercolor property, which browsers apply to ALL borders inside the table:

```
OnRowDataBound="MyGrid_RowDataBound"

protected void MyGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     foreach (TableCell tc in e.Row.Cells)
     {
         tc.Attributes["style"] = "border-color: #000";
     }
}
```

I put out a blog post about this - check Lee Dumond's comment:

http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2009/05/31/Set-Color-of-GridLines-in-Gridview.aspx#comment

Comment: Bear in mind that, IIRC, those are generally applied to the TDs, rather than the whole row. You might want to look into the CSS Control Adapters (OOB in VS2010): http://www.asp.net/CssAdapters/

Comment: CSS Adapters are really not necessary here and are in the process of being phased out. I'm currently working on two separate projects where the App_Browsers folder causes really serious problems with FrontPage Extensions when deployed to a live server.

Comment: Thanks, that's fixed it! I've managed to extract it to a separate CSS file by using the CssClass property of the HeaderStyle tag.

Comment: They're not being phased out so much as they're becoming a first class option in VS2010/ASP.NET 4.0 ;)

Comment: thanks for the heads-up Zhaph... I'm still struggling with the VTI folder issue...